# Get `export {default as MyName} from './some-module';` to work with Jest (create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, jestjs, create-react-app

I keep getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined` when using the following syntax for re-exporting a module in JS:

```js
export {default as MyName} from './some-module';
```

This works with create-react-app but the included Jest tests can't deal with it. Does Jest not use the same babel presets? Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: "Does Jest not use the same babel presets?" As far as I know, no, it doesn't. Have you seen this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/?

Comment: @adamtropp The link looks incomplete, can you post it again?

Comment: Haha you are right https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-jest

Comment: I guess this could be used additionally, I'm having troubles understanding what is supported and why it's not everything..

Comment: I dont know for sure, but you might find this helpful https://thetrevorharmon.com/blog/configuring-jest-and-enzyme-in-create-react-app-on-typescript. As for why not everything is supported, create-react-app is meant to be an opinionated framework, so it only supports one config without ejecting. I have ran into similar difficulties trying to extend the esling config, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I tricked myself into believing this to be syntax issue while it was actually a cyclical import problem.

It didn't turn up before because the application imported things in a different order than the tests.